Unexpected behaviour of `\label` inside equation environment - Cross-referencing: check that all cross-references are to earlier objects
In this post, the user egreg provides a MWE (proof of concept) that redefines \label, \ref, \eqref, so that \ref and \eqref produce a warning when the corresponding label occurs later in the code. I saw that the code does no work as intended when the \label is attached to an equation environment: \eqref gives warnings regardless of the position of the equation in the code. Here is egreg's code, with my tests done in section C.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@label\label
\let\latex@ref\ref
\def\label#1{\global\@namedef{LABEL@#1@USED}{}\latex@label{#1}}
\def\ref#1{%
  \ifcsname LABEL@#1@USED\endcsname\else
    \@latex@warning{Forward Reference '#1'}%
  \fi
  \latex@ref{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A}\label{a}

This refers to \ref{a} and to \ref{b}.

\section{B}\label{b}

OK.

%%% from here, I am doing my own tests
\section{C}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:first}
   3+2=5
\end{equation}

\makeatletter
\begin{equation}{\global\@namedef{LABEL@eq:second@USED}{}\latex@label{eq:second}} % this is simply the definition of \label{eq:second}
   2+4=6
\end{equation}
\makeatother

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:my_theorem}
   10+10=20
\end{theorem}

Referencing equation \eqref{eq:first}, equation \eqref{eq:second}, and Theorem \ref{thm:my_theorem}.
% \eqref{eq:first} gives an unexpected warning...
% The reference to eq:second instead doesn't give warnings, although I simply substituted \label with its definition.
% Referencing the theorem works fine. 

\end{document}


I get the warnings:
Forward Reference 'b' on input line 22.
Forward Reference 'eq:first' on input line 45.

My questions are: why is the command \eqef{eq:first} giving a warning, despite the reference occurring after the label \label{eq:first} (and why \eqref{eq:second} is not)? And how to modify the code to make it work as intended?
The same happens if I use\ref instead of \eqref. It seems that \global\@namedef inside the redefined \label is not working properly in the equation environment. The strange thing though is that, if I substitute \label{eq:second} with its definition as in the preamble, as I did in the above code, I don't get any warnings.

As you have loaded amsmath if you put \show\label into the equation you will see that it has definition
> \label=macro:
->\ifx \df@label \@empty \else \@amsmath@err {Multiple \string \label 's: label
 '\df@label ' will be lost}\@eha \fi \gdef \df@label .

so not using the standard latex definition. amsmath needs this for alignments, less so for equation but it redefines it there as well for consistency.
load amsmath after your change:
\documentclass{article}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@label\label
\let\latex@ref\ref
\def\label#1{\global\@namedef{LABEL@#1@USED}{}\latex@label{#1}}
\def\ref#1{%
  \ifcsname LABEL@#1@USED\endcsname\else
    \@latex@warning{Forward Reference '#1'}%
  \fi
  \latex@ref{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\section{A}\label{a}

This refers to \ref{a} and to \ref{b}.

\section{B}\label{b}

OK.

%%% from here, I am doing my own tests
\section{C}

\begin{equation}
  % \show\label
  \label{eq:first}
   3+2=5
\end{equation}


\makeatletter
\begin{equation}{\global\@namedef{LABEL@eq:second@USED}{}\latex@label{eq:second}} % this is simply the definition of \label{eq:second}
   2+4=6
\end{equation}
\makeatother

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:my_theorem}
   10+10=20
\end{theorem}

Referencing equation \eqref{eq:first}, equation \eqref{eq:second}, and Theorem \ref{thm:my_theorem}.
% \eqref{eq:first} gives an unexpected warning...
% The reference to eq:second instead doesn't give warnings, although I simply substituted \label with its definition.
% Referencing the theorem works fine. 

\end{document}


Ohhh, I see. Thank you, I did not know the command \show, it would have taken me ages to figure this out on my own

instead of redefining \label you could use \AddToHookWithArguments{label}  {\global\@namedef{LABEL@#1@USED}{}}. That should also work if amsmath is loaded first.

@UlrikeFischer Does load order matter for the label hook?
